# In Magento 2 after installtion i get magento-version dev-develop

Tags: magento2

I'm using Magento 2 version 2.4.6, and I've noticed that in admin panel show dev-develop version.

I've tried for chnage version but i don't get solution. However, none of these attempts have successfully resolved the problem.

Has anyone else encountered a similar compatibility issue with Magento 2 version 2.4.6? If so, what steps did you take to resolve it? Are there any specific patches, updates, or workarounds that can help mitigate this issue?

**Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!**[image]

Comment: Check Magento version from CLI : php  bin/magento --version

Comment: Another way to check Magento version is not using any tool but merely adding /magento_version following your domain URL and then go searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this you can change in composer.json file i have prvided link for this below

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cNSBqq4tlibHUp3kaJLrpG5Sga8fdJpLJaWNSV9Oe2w/edit?usp=sharing

after update that run composer update command and magento all command and show 2.4.6 version